# Weird colored terminal response by git

Tags: git, terminal, bitbucket

Recently I was scared to death by the following colored terminal response.

It was triggered by the git push command.

Does anybody have a clue where this colored response comes from?[image: Screennshot]

Comment: The `remote:` indicates that it was printed by the remote system during or after the push operation, perhaps by a post-receive hook.

Comment: @DarkFalcon It completely surprised me. What do you mean by a post receive hook?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive

Comment: Just seen this for the first time today - not seen it before and have been using Bitbucket for years. Didn't even see it earlier today when I pushed on a different project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a guess, but perhaps the fine folks at Atlassian who run BitBucket are celebrating [the Supreme Court ruling on gay marriage](http://www.cnn.com/2015/06/26/politics/supreme-court-same-sex-marriage-ruling/). That is their logo in rainbow-colored ASCII art...

Comment: Quite blunt a way to celebrate something if you ask me. But plus points for originality though.

Comment: Many US corps are decorating in celebration... See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow?cb=1