# Atlassian rainbow

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

I just came across a git response in the form of a rainbow, when pushing to my bitbucket repository:

[image]

Does anybody have a clue what this is related to?

The last time they pulled [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081865/3646263) was in solidarity with [Supreme Court ruling on gay marriage](http://www.cnn.com/2015/06/26/politics/supreme-court-same-sex-marriage-ruling/).

Note that this is *not* a duplicate of [Atlassian “logo” after pushing to bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081919/atlassian-logo-after-pushing-to-bitbucket), since that one was in celebration of the [Supreme Court ruling on gay marriage](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/14pdf/14-556_3204.pdf). This one is in celebration of the LGBT pride month, June.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=pride+month

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Atlassian "logo" after pushing to bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081919/atlassian-logo-after-pushing-to-bitbucket)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [June is the LGBT pride month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay_pride#LGBT_Pride_Month). Judging from the color scheme, it's probably a similar display of solidarity.