# Git remote prints a multicolored message after pushing

Tags: git

I was pushing my code to my remote repo when I saw this strange multicolored output on the command line:

[image: Multicoloured pattern]

I have no idea what that means. Did I break something?

Comment: I don't know exactly how they did it but my guess is whatever remote you're pushing to, they configured it to do this

Comment: also, this doesn't have anything to do with ruby so I am untagging it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Atlassian "logo" after pushing to bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081919/atlassian-logo-after-pushing-to-bitbucket)

Comment: More topical duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50937041/744178

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### WHAT IS IT

From [Bitbucket support](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/16537/gay-pride-flag-rainbow-flag-lgbt-movement) 4 days ago:

> **This message is in honor of the pride celebrations here in San Francisco.** From time to time we add images to the push process and/or
>   UI to recognize holidays and current events. It is simply a nod to the
>   great diversity of our customers, employees, and integrators.

#### HOW TO DISABLE

> You can turn off the terminal message by going to Bitbucket settings,
>   and unchecking Console messages under Profile. The UI logo will be
>   restored back to our normal Bitbucket logo next week.

---

#### HOW DOES A REMOTE SERVICE PRINT CUSTOM MESSAGES

Really, this all comes down to `git` and the 3 hooks you can use to respond to incoming requests to alter the repository:

- **`pre-receive`**

  - executed every time somebody uses `git push` to push commits to the repository. Called before anything is updated.
- **`update`**

  - called after `pre-receive`, and it works much the same way. It’s still called before anything is actually updated, but it’s called separately for each ref that was pushed.
- **`post-receive`**

  - called after a successful `push` operation, making it **a good place to perform notifications**.

So judging by the topic at hand, I feel its safe to say `bitbucket` probably used the `post-receive` hook service built into their platform in order to send the ASCII art in the original post. Its also worth mentioning that they recently added a few other messages, most notably, the one that provides a direct link to creating a pull request for the branch you've just pushed to (as long as it isn't master).

#### Other, more notable usages for this type of technology

- [CI services](https://github.com/ligurio/awesome-ci#list-of-continuous-integration-services)
- [Deployment tools](https://github.com/delirehberi/amazing-deployment#tools) (because automation is cool)
- [Slack Github notifications](https://github.com/integrations/slack)

  - (might be worth mentioning Github has built a whole API for 3rd party developers to access, but nonetheless, it is using the same service)

***I hope this helps!***